# How to simplify Dirac's delta with complicated argument?

Tags: dirac-delta

My professor claims:
$$\delta(\frac{r^2-a^2}{(r^2+a^2)^3})=4a^5\delta(r-a)$$
where $a>0$ is a constant.
I completely don't see this, help?

Comment: I think sth is missing in the equation in the question, see my answer

Comment: Presumably $r>0$.

Comment: @Qmechanic oh yes, I forgot to write, this is in the spherical coordinate system, so r>=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my simple knowledge in distributions
$$ \delta(f(x)) = \sum_i\frac{1}{|f'(x_i)|}\delta(x-x_i) $$
where {$x_i$ } are *simple* zeros of $f(x)$. So that means
$$ \delta(\frac{r^2-a^2}{(r^2+a^2)^3}) = 4a^5(\delta(x-a)+\delta(x+a)) $$
where
$$
f'(x)|_{x=a} = \left(\frac{2 x}{\left(a^2+x^2\right)^3}-\frac{6 x \left(x^2-a^2\right)}{\left(a^2+x^2\right)^4}\right)\Bigg|_{x=a} = \frac{1}{4a^5}
$$
and
$$
f'(x)|_{x=-a} = \left(\frac{2 x}{\left(a^2+x^2\right)^3}-\frac{6 x \left(x^2-a^2\right)}{\left(a^2+x^2\right)^4}\right)\Bigg|_{x=-a} = -\frac{1}{4a^5}
$$

Comment: See a proof of this formula [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/662226)

Comment: See as well [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2399294)

Comment: I persume then, since r>0, the other term neccessarily dies out then